# problem on calculating mean a column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, mean, np

I used Python to calculate a column average in a dataframe. I used the following command to calculate  the summation of data in defined column. But, I do not exactly know why the output result is just appended data without any summation.

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how = 'inner', on = 'key')
df3
df3['age'].sum()
```

The output result is:

```
>>key      data1        data2   age

42           0.01         1200  17

101          0.02          523  10

>>1710
```

So, as you see the sum function is just append '17' and '10' and the result is 1710. For mean function I again get 1710/2 = 855.

Could you please put any comment?

Comment: Is necessary convert column to numeric

Comment: Yes. Thanks. It works with pd.to_numeric()